# How can we generate a list which it element is dict?

Tags: python

Before Question:

1. There are may android applications
2. There are lots of versions under same application
3. got the newest application(versionCode indicate the newest)

eg：

```
/path/to/apk1/history/v1/xxx.apk versionCode=1
/path/to/apk1/history/v1.3/xxx.apk versionCode=1.3
/path/to/apk/v2/xxx.apk versionCode=3
```

well,`/path/to/apk/v2/xxx.apk` win out.

## What's I do?

1. analysis the *versionCode* from apk file with below function.

   `def analysisApk(apkPath):
   outfile = os.popen("./aapt d badging %s " % apkPath,'r').read()
   match = re.compile("package: name='(\S+)' versionCode='(\d+)' versionName='(\S+)'").match(outfile)
   packageName=match.group(1)
   versionCode = match.group(2)`
2. append the unique dict to the global list which store the application we want.
3. I can generate a single dict,but I don't know how to  generate a dict list
4. I can generate a dict list this `{packageName:"com.xxx.1",versionCode:2,apkPath:"/path/to/1.apk"}`
5. unfortunately I do not konw how to append the dicts to  below list

   > [{packageName:"com.xxx.1",versionCode:2,apkPath:"/path/to/1.apk"},{packageName:"com.xxx.2",versionCode:2,apkPath:"/path/to/2.0.apk"},<s>{{packageName:"com.xxx.2",versionCode:1,apkPath:"/path/to/v2.apk"}}</s>,...,{{packageName:"com.xxx.n",versionCode:2,apkPath:"/path/to/n.apk"}}]

**the <s>del line</s> need remove from the list(a newest versionCode coming..)**

this quote does not the really result ,only example for us to understand this quesiton

## What's my Question:

1. how to generate the dict list step by step follow my point?
2. Is there any others ideas for this problem?

Comment: That is a list of dictionaries?

Comment: You want the path to an .apk with the max `versionCode`, am I right?

Comment: I think you're actually asking about regular expression that will match all occurrences of packageName and VersionCode from the file? If so, try re.findall() or better re.finditer()

Comment: In question's title you asked how you are going to get a list of dicts, but in your post it seems that you already have a list of dicts, so...?

Comment: @Sayse Yes,a list of dictionaries

Comment: @Alex.S ,great! I want to get the .apk path with the max `versionCode`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do a list comprehension as such:

```
list_of_dicts = [extract_all_the_info(line) for line in source]
```

where `extract_all_the_info()` does the regular expression that you do above, and return a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed, on basis of your regular expression, that your input is a file with lines like these:

```
lines = [
    "package: name='/path/to/apk1/history/v1/xxx.apk' versionCode='1' versionName='one'",
    "package: name='/path/to/apk1/history/v1.3/xxx.apk' versionCode='1.3' versionName='two'",
    "package: name='/path/to/apk/v2/xxx.apk' versionCode='3' versionName='three'",
]
```

You can get the lines as a list via the `.readlines()` function of the filehandle.

Then you can iterate over them, use whatever regex you need to extract your values and put them in a dictionary which is recreated each loop (apk_dict).

Before going into the next loop we put our dictionary into a list outside the loop (apk_list) with `.append()`.

```
import re

apk_list = []
for line in lines:
    apk_dict = {}
    match = re.match("package: name='(\S+)' versionCode='(\d+)' versionName='(\S+)'", line)
    if not match:
        continue
    apk_dict['name'] = match.group(1)
    apk_dict['versionCode'] = match.group(2)
    apk_dict['versionName'] = match.group(3)
    apk_list.append(apk_dict)

print(apk_list)
```

apk_list will then have:

```
[
    {
        'versionName': 'one',
        'versionCode': '1',
        'name': '/path/to/apk1/history/v1/xxx.apk'
    },
    {
        'versionName': 'three',
        'versionCode': '3',
        'name': '/path/to/apk/v2/xxx.apk'
    }
]
```

The second line got dropped for reasons I explain below.

**Some things to notice:**

You are trying to use `.compile()` on your regular expression. This does not do what you think it does. To match the expression with a string use `.match()`. Compile creates a kind of 'expression object' which you can use instead of an expression.

Next your `(\d+)` will not work for things like '1.3' as there is a non digit character inbetween the numbers. Something like `(\S+)`

You also have to handle failed matching attempts. I simply skip the line with `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to get the path to an apk with the max `versionCode` using dictionaries would be an overkill. 
Use two variables: `path` and `version`. Open the first apk, save apkPath in `path` and versionCode in `version`. Go to the next apk. If its versionCode is higher than `version`, set `path` to apkPath. Go to the next, repeat until you processed all apks. After that you'll have in `path` the path to the apk with the highest `versionCode`.

PS. And to add something to a list use "`append()`":

```
new_list = old_list.append(item)
```